# How to convert JSON file content into Powershell object in Powershell runbook?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

I'm trying to convert JSON file  which is present in storage account data into Powershell object. But I'm not getting the proper output. Output does not contain proper values.

My code:

```
$storageAccountKey = "xxxx"
$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'xxxx' -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$b='C:\Temp\Scheduled.json'
Get-AzureStorageFileContent -Path $b -ShareName "file-share-name" 
$newScheduledRules =  Get-Content -Raw   $b | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output ("########newScheduledRules::###########" + $newScheduledRules)
```

Output:

```
Could not get the storage context.  Please pass in a storage context or set the current storage context.
########newScheduledRules::###########@{Scheduled=System.Object[]; Fusion=System.Object[]; MLBehaviorAnalytics=System.Object[]; MicrosoftSecurityIncidentCreation=System.Object[]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and followed below process and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorage):

**Scheduled.json:**

```
{
"Rithwik":"Hello",
"Chotu":"Bojja"
}
```

[image]

Firstly, I have created Storage account and then added a Scheduled.json in file share as below:

[image]

Now i have created a runbook and excuted below script in runbook as below:

```
$storageAccountKey = "PFHxFbVmAEvwBM6/9kW4nORJYA+AStA2QQ1A=="
$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'rithwik' -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$out = "$($env:TEMP)\$([guid]::NewGuid())"
New-Item -Path $out -ItemType Directory -Force
Get-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName "rithwik" -Context $Context -Path 'Scheduled.json' -Destination $out -Force
$newScheduledRules = Get-Content -Path "$out\Scheduled.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output ("########newScheduledRules::###########" + $newScheduledRules)
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Here **$out** is the Destination Variable.

**-Path**  should be Only the file name `Scheduled.json` in
`Get-AzStorageFileContent` command.

Comment: Hi Ritwik .. Can you please look into this query ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75136560/can-we-call-a-runbook-from-another-runbook-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `Get-AzureStorageFileContent` is missing `-Context` parameter. It should be something like this

```
$OutPath = "$($env:TEMP)\$([guid]::NewGuid())"
New-Item -Path $OutPath -ItemType Directory -Force

$storageContext = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName xxxx -Name xxxx).Context

Get-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName "file-share-name" -Context $storageContext -Path 'Scheduled.json' -Destination $OutPath -Force
$newScheduledRules = Get-Content -Path "$OutPath\Scheduled.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output ("########newScheduledRules::###########" + $newScheduledRules)
```

Comment: Hi Duc Nguyen, able to sort out the context issue. But the json content is coming in the incorrect format while converting to powershell object. Output have been mentioned in the question itself

Comment: Look at your code, I think you haven't specified the destination of the file that you want to download.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestoragefilecontent?view=azurermps-6.13.0#-destination) for more information.